# Get Used rather than Provisioned space in PowerCLI

Tags: vmware-vsphere, powercli

I'm trying to run a capacity report, and when I run the `Get-HardDisk` cmdlet in PowerCLI, the value it returns for CapacityKB is the Provisioned space. For example, let's say I've thin provisioned a 200GB disk, which is currently using say 30GB, it returns the 200GB value.

Is there any way I can get the other value? I need to know how much disk space is actually being used on the LUN by the vmdk file. My PowerCLI version is 5.0.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just query the VM with get-vm and add `| Select UsedSpaceGB`.

For example, you could type:

```
get-vm | Select Name, UsedSpaceGB, ProvisionedSpaceGB
```

Comment: To write this information into a .CSV file just append `|export-csv "C:\Path\to\my\file.csv"`.